# add a list element after clicking a anchor tag at a desired position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a `<li>` after i click an anchor tag (quick view, which shows when you hover over the gray boxes). The logic is if the the element is am clicking is at at a position which is a multiple of 3 then I adding the `<li>` right after that, which works fine. The problem is when I have a remainder of 1 and 2. It is moving the `<li>` right next it. If the description doesn't make sense please let me know and I can try to explain it more. Here is the algorithm

```
if r = 0 
    do (add an element at this + 1);
if r <= 1
    do (add an element at this +3);
if r = 2
    do (add an element at this + 2);

Where r is the remainder, r = p/3 ..p is the position of the element
```

Here is the JS

```
$('.quick-view').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $('.product-drawer').remove();
  var productIndex = $(this).parent().attr('data-loopcount');
  var r = productIndex % 3;
  var index = $(this).parent().index(); 
    if(r == 0){
        $('<li class="product-drawer">'+Number(index + 1) +'</li>').insertAfter($(this).parent());
    }else if(r == 2){
        $('<li class="product-drawer">'+Number(index + 2) +'</li>').insertAfter($(this).parent()).eq(Number(index + 2));
    }else if(r <= 1){
      $('<li class="product-drawer">'+Number(index + 3) +'</li>').insertAfter($(this).parent()).eq(Number(index + 3));
    }
})
```

here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/fnuyq9tw/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the call to `.eq()`: that only makes sense if you apply it to a jQuery object that has multiple matches. But `$(this).parent()` will only return one element, so applying `eq()` to that makes no sense.

Instead, make use of `.next()`.

Here is a solution based on that, which also minimises a bit the code to avoid repetition:

```
$('.quick-view').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.product-drawer').remove();
    var $curr = $(this).parent();
    var productIndex = $curr.attr('data-loopcount');
    var r = productIndex % 3;
    var index = $(this).parent().index() + [1, 3, 2][r];
    var $li = $('<li class="product-drawer">' + index +'</li>');
    var $target = [$curr, $curr.next().next(), $curr.next()][r];
    $li.insertAfter($target);
})
```

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/fnuyq9tw/11/).

Further work might be necessary, depending on what you are after. For instance, the newly inserted `li` elements, may need to get some other attributes. Also, the selection based on `data-loopcount` is a bit obscure. Without further context it is hard to imagine what purpose it has.

Comment: selection based on data-loopcount is obscure indeed. I could just build the logic based on the zero based index.

Answer (score 1):

Is not realy clear ! but I think you want something similar to this:

```
    if(r == 0){
        $('<li class="product-drawer">'+Number(index + 1) +'</li>').insertAfter($(this).parent());
    }else if(r == 2){
        $('<li class="product-drawer">'+Number(index + 2) +'</li>').insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().find('li[data-loopcount=' + (index + 2) + ']'));
    }else if(r <= 1){
      $('<li class="product-drawer">'+Number(index + 3) +'</li>').insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().find('li[data-loopcount=' + (index + 3) + ']'));
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fnuyq9tw/10/)